# AWS lambda function questions

Tags: python

I'm looking at an example for python AWS `lambda` function and I had a few questions.

1. For this method:

   ```
   def create_favorite_color_attributes(favorite_color):
       return {"favoriteColor": favorite_color}
   ```

   What does this colon do in the `return` statement?
2. Also, for this (part) method:

   ```
   def get_news(intent, session):
       card_title = intent['name']
       session_attributes = {}
       should_end_session = False

       if 'Color' in intent['slots']:
           favorite_color = intent['slots']['Color']['value']
           session_attributes = create_favorite_color_attributes(favorite_color)
   ```

   Where is `'Color'` defined? It looks like `'Color'` is equal to what a person would respond to alexa saying their favorite color. Or is it checking of `'Color'` is a slot category? If the second, then for `favorite_color = intent['slots']['Color']['value']`, where is `'value'` defined?

Also if anyone has any tutorials for python amazon `lamdba` functions for alexa skills, please let me know.

Comment: The `:`  means that it defines a dictionary. Please read the **[Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)** to understand the Python syntax. (You should be using [Python 3.6](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-lambda-supports-python-3-6/))

Answer (score 1):

None of code from your question looks like lambda. Amazon lambda is just a functions which accepts two parameters "event" and "context". After that you can create an event which will trigger that lambda and give it some context.
Event can be what ever you want: HTTP request, S3 event or Alexa event.

Answer (score 0):

For Your question,
1) colon mean  it defines a dictionary data structure.
2) 'Color' is a String value, it was defined when it was used.. But u can not retrieve it once u used it.
FYI, python is fun, read the tutorial. :)